# Can I redirect the user to another page while uploading files to the server?

Tags: php, redirect, upload

I have a php script that: compresses and sends to the server images uploaded by the user, sends the text inputs as email, and then does a redirect with header('location:...').
So, the user needs to wait for this process's finishing to be redirected to another page. It takes too much time to keep them waiting. How could I work around this problem?
I really appreciate any help you can provide.

Comment: Nope. And the reason: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2929939/redirecting-before-post-upload-has-been-completed

Comment: You could try doing the upload via AJAX, and meanwhile opening the next page in a new tab/window. Depends how you want the UX to work, though.

Comment: @ADyson, yes, I'm figuring out about asynchronous file uploading with ajax, ty